# Удаляет несколько элементов сразу через ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Добрый день уважаемые профессионалы.
Хочу реализовать удаление без перезагрузки с выводом модального окна для подтверждения удаления.

- Статья 1 | удалить
- Статья 2 | удалить

Если я нажму удалить статью 1, потом нажму нет, после нажму удалить статью 2 и подтвержу удаление, то произойдёт удаление и статьи 1 и статьи 2.
Что я делаю не так?

**Еще если несколько раз подрядят (например 5 раз) нажимать удалить а потом нажимать НЕТ, а на 6-й раз нажать ДА, то скрипт (case 'yes') сработает 6 раз.**

```js
$("body").on('click', '.del_row_file', function() {
  var table = $(this).attr("rel")
  var row = $(this).attr("id")
  //console.log(row)
  $('body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  });
  $('#bg_modal_window').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $('.answer_modal').html('Удалить выбранный элемент?');

  $('.clicket').click(function() {
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
      case 'no':

        $('#bg_modal_window').css({
          'display': 'none'
        });
        $('body').css({
          'overflow': ''
        });
        break;
      case 'yes':
      console.log('мы тут N-раз')
        $('.row_id_' + row).remove();
        $('#bg_modal_window').css({
              'display': 'none'
            });
            $('body').css({
              'overflow': ''
            });
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#bg_modal_window {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 9002;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}

#modal_window {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #171a24;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#modal_window .border {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#modal_window .border h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#modal_window .answer_modal {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#modal_window .answer_modal .text {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#modal_window .button_footer {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_yes {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #5BC0DE;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5BC0DE;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_no {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #BF2D37;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #BF2D37;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_yes:hover {
  border: 2px solid #5BC0DE;
  background: #5BC0DE;
  color: #FFF;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_no:hover {
  border: 2px solid #BF2D37;
  background: #BF2D37;
  color: #FFF;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row_id_1">
    <td>Статья 1</td>
    <td>
      <a class="list_button del_row_file" title="Удалить" id="1" rel="news">Удалить</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row_id_2">
    <td>Статья 2</td>
    <td>
      <a class="list_button del_row_file" title="Удалить" id="2" rel="news">Удалить</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<div id="bg_modal_window">
  <div id="modal_window">
    <div class="border">
      <h3>Подтвердите действие:</h3>
      <div class="answer_modal">

      </div>
      <div class="button_footer">
        <span class="b_no clicket" id="no">Нет</span>
        <span class="b_yes clicket" id="yes">Да</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: switch ($(this).attr('id')) { это зачем так? id элемента должен быть уникальным, а у вас он повторяется для каждого <tr

Comment: Так он у меня уникальный. один id='no', второй id='yes'. Они не повторяются. Это кнопки всплывающего окна для подтверждения удаления.

Comment: `console.log()` вам в помощь? Выводите все значения всех переменных. И даю 100%, что вы найдёте баг и без сообщества. Не хаватет ещё `html` кода.

Comment: Плодятся клики, вот вам и после каждого следующего раза будет добавлять еще клики. Чтобы ваш скрипт поправить, нужно добавить после блока `switch` - добавить `$(this).unbind('click');`. или использовать аналог `.off`, так как `unbind` в 3+ уже устарел и на замену встал `off`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var targetId = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $modal = $(this);
    targetId = e.relatedTarget.id;
  });

  $("#yes").click(function() {
    $("tr #" + targetId).parent().parent().remove();
    $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
  });
  $("#no").click(function() {
    $('#edit-modal').css('display', 'none')
  });
});
```

```css
#bg_modal_window {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 9002;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}

#modal_window {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #171a24;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#modal_window .border {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#modal_window .border h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#modal_window .answer_modal {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#modal_window .answer_modal .text {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#modal_window .button_footer {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_yes {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #5BC0DE;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5BC0DE;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_no {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #BF2D37;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #BF2D37;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_yes:hover {
  border: 2px solid #5BC0DE;
  background: #5BC0DE;
  color: #FFF;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#modal_window .button_footer .b_no:hover {
  border: 2px solid #BF2D37;
  background: #BF2D37;
  color: #FFF;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="row_id_1">
      <td>Статья 1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal" class="list_button del_row_file" title="Удалить" id="1" rel="news">Удалить</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_id_2">
      <td>Статья 2</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal" class="list_button del_row_file" title="Удалить" id="2" rel="news">Удалить</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>



  <div id="edit-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="modal_window">
      <div class="border">
        <h3>Подтвердите действие:</h3>
        <div class="answer_modal">

        </div>
        <div class="button_footer">
          <span class="b_no clicket" data-dismiss="modal" id="no">Нет</span>
          <span class="b_yes clicket" id="yes">Да</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Коммент @And Решил проблему.
Добавил после `switch`:

```
 $('.clicket').unbind('click');
```

В итоге:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("body").on('click', '.del_row_file', function() {
    var table = $(this).attr("rel")
    var row = $(this).attr("id")
    //console.log(row)
    $('body').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});  
    $('#bg_modal_window').css({'display': 'block'});
    $('.answer_modal').html('Удалить выбранный элемент?');

    $('.clicket').click(function () {
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case 'no':
                $('#bg_modal_window').css({'display': 'none'});
                $('body').css({'overflow': ''});

            break;
            case 'yes':
                console.log('тут');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {del_row_file: row, table: table},
                    success: function(res){
                        var res = JSON.parse(res);
                        console.log(res)
                        if(res['error'] != ''){
                            $('.answer').append(res['error']);  
                        } else {
                            $('.answer').append(res['success']);
                            $('.row_id_'+res['id']).remove();
                        }
                        $('#bg_modal_window').css({'display': 'none'});
                        $('body').css({'overflow': ''});
                    }
                });
            break;
        }     
        $('.clicket').unbind('click');
   });
});
});
```

Теперь работает нормально.